# Bash script generates log but not when executed via crontab. Why?

Tags: bash, cron

My bash script generates a log file but not when it's executed via crontab.

Why is that?

Crontab entry.

```
55 0 * * * ~/scripts/BackupPC.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I know that crontab is working because I checked /var/log/syslog

```
$ cat syslog | grep BackupRpi.sh
Jul  7 00:55:01 rpi CRON[13455]: (pi) CMD (sh ~/scripts/BackupRpi.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

My script. The log file is created when I execute it manually via **BackupRpi.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
fn=${logsdir}/RPI-`date +%I-%M-%S-%p--%d-%b-%Y`.txt

echo "[START]  $(date)" >> $fn
rsync -avXP --delete-excluded --info=progress2 --no-i-r -R --log-file=${fn} ${HOME}  /media/hitachi/backup/rpi
echo "[END]  $(date)" >> $fn
```

Comment: When troubleshooting, redirecting output (especially error output) to /dev/null just hides what's going wrong. Try redirecting it to a log file instead, something like `>/tmp/BackupRpi.log 2>&1`

Comment: The variable `fn` is defined using the variable `logsdir`: This variable is unknow to the system and hence it will attempt to write the output to `/RPI-xxxx.txt`

Comment: @kvantour You're right. The variable $logsdir is set in my .bashrc file via ```export logsdir=~/logs```

Comment: @kvantour Any idea how I would make that variable available to the crontab environment? I'd rather not set it in the script itself (the logging does work when I declare $logsdir in the script itself).

Comment: So I'm sourcing my bashrc which sets $logsdir but the log is still not being generated.```1 0 * * * source /home/pi/.bashrc; ~/scripts/BackupRpi.sh >/dev/null 2>&1```

Comment: @Bassam Have you captured & examined the script's output (especially error output) yet?

Comment: @GordonDavisson Hmm I'm not sure if there are any issues there. What I mean is this: when I manually execute this script, all the errors that occur (such as if source folders that are to be backup that are missing, for example) log fine to the log file ($fn). I also know that crontab is working because ```$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep BackupPC.sh
Jul 16 00:05:01 rpi CRON[11625]: (pi) CMD (source /home/pi/.bashrc; ~/scripts/BackupPC.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)``` Is there something else that I should check? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Change the cron entry as recommended in my first comment, let it run, then check *that* log file.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Ok sorry I didn't understand what you meant but I get it now. I did what you said and I see a permission error ```/home/pi/scripts/BackupRpi.sh: line 6: /RPI-02-10-01-AM--17-Jul-2020.txt: Permission denied```. I get what the error means but I don't know how to get around it. $logsdir is declared in my .bashrc file and crontab is unable to access that information. I've tried sourcing my .bashrc before executing the script but it appears that it doesn't help. Any ideas?